# Text size in px will be invisible is somehow resized

Tags: standards

My page is white and the background image for links is mainly black. I need the link text to be white to be visible over the black background.

Ive set the text size in pixels, but if it was somehow resized then the text may not be visible over the page as its also white.

Is this OK? Generally zooming seems to be done by scaling the whole page not just resizing text. Also ive used px, which generally dont resize. If this isnt OK, how else can you have white link text over a dark background?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just have dynamic sizes for the menu items ?
That way if the text is resized then so will the menu item in which it is contained.

if you use css and be sure to validate your markup using w3c the fallout should be minimal as most browsers will try and render standards compliant code reasonably well.

I'm sure you've seen this before:
http://validator.w3.org/

If nothing else it will at least look good or poor in everything rather than good in some and poor in all so that makes the issues a bit easy to pin down.

oh um ...

how would the text be resized anyway ?
To my knowledge unless you provide a different / optional style that can be added or removed text sizes are fixed, for example:

```
<div style="font-size:10px;"> test </div>
```

Assuming the page renders correctly that "test" div will always render the text at 10px ... if the user uses their browser to make the size bigger or smaller the entire div scales not just the text, this is the reason for standards ... makes that kind of problem where the text resizes and the div doesnt go away.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, i think you've misunderstood me. The amount of text will rename constant im only concerned about my user's browser settings and accessibility devices, etc resizing the text.

Comment: then i think i've probably covered that ... as long as the device is rendering the web page using a browser that respects web standards and your markup is standards compliant you should be fine. as you suggested the application the user uses would scale the application to fit the users screen .. the user would then need to zoom in or out as appropriate